# Needed explanation on Express MiddleWares with next

Tags: express

I have only one MiddleWare with next called inside, and the request-response cycle is ended even though i did not use the res.send(), how is that?

```
app.use("/", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(`${req.method} ${req.path} - ${req.ip}`);
  next();
});
```

Comment: Why you know `the request-response cycle is ended even though i did not use the res.send()`?

Comment: it didn't hang on the browser.

Comment: What is response on the browser?

Comment: response in the browser Cannot GET /

Comment: Because you do not have any router to handle the GET / request, then express response 404 error.

Comment: but it did log in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211773/discussion-between-seif-eddine-slimene-and-hoangdv).